# Constructor TransportClient in class TransportClient cannot be accessed

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I wrote the following class for indexing documents in ElasticSearch:

```
import java.net.InetAddress
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress
import play.api.libs.json.{JsString, JsValue}

/**
  * Created by liana on 12/07/16.
  */
class ElasticSearchConnector {

  private var transportClient: TransportClient = null
  private val host = "localhost"
  private val port = 9300
  private val cluster = "elasticsearch"
  private val indexName = "tests"
  private val docType = "test"

  def configElasticSearch(): Unit =
  {
    val settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", cluster).build()
    transportClient = new TransportClient(settings)
    transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port.toInt))
  }

  def putText(json: String, id: Int): String =
  {
    val response = transportClient.prepareIndex(indexName, docType, id)
                                  .setSource(json)
                                  .get()
    val responseId = response.getId
    responseId
  }
}
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
val json = """val jsonString =
{
"title": "Elastic",
"price": 2000,
"author":{
"first": "Zachary",
"last": "Tong";
}
}"""

val ec = new ElasticSearchConnector()
ec.configElasticSearch()
val id = ec.putText(json)
System.out.println(id)
```

This is the error message I got:

> Error:(28, 23) constructor TransportClient in class TransportClient
>   cannot be accessed in class ElasticSearchConnector
>       transportClient = new TransportClient(settings)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In the Elasticsearch Connector API the TransportClient class has no public constructor, but one declared private constructor. Thus you cannot "new" up an instance of the TransportClient directly. The API utilizes the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) fairly heavily so in order to create an instance of the TransportClient you will need to do something like:

```
val settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", cluster).build()
val transportClient = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port.toInt))
```